# Why does static cast eat reference?

Tags: c++, static-cast

Consider the following code:

```
struct base {};
struct derived : public base {};

int main() {
    derived d = {};
    derived* ptr_d = &d;
    derived*& ref_ptr_d = ptr_d;

    base*& ref_ptr_b = static_cast<base*&>(ref_ptr_d); // this won't compile
    (void) ref_ptr_b;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `ref_ptr_d` is interpreted as `derived*` instead of `derived*&` and the cast is invalid?

I can reproduce it on *MSVC*, and *gcc* compilers.

Comment: That is how a reference works.  It is just a substitute name.  Anywhere you have the reference name pretend you have the original name.

Comment: The duplicate was the very first hit on Google for [stack overflow invalid cast reference to pointer].

Comment: there's no difference between `int a, &b=a, &c=b;` and `int a, &b=a, &c=a;`. In both cases `a`, `b`, and `c` are all the same thing.